# Datetime parameter in Web service causing issues with colon: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Is there anything that can be done from the client side if the server is giving me this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (:).

for the request of type:

```
https://x.net/api/customers('2017-02-02T10:29:06Z')
```

Or this can only be fixed in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ISO 8601 format?

Something like:

```
customers/YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ
```

Comment: isn't working. i tried "('20170202T102906Z')". error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Why the parenthesis?  Did you try passing it as I stated above?

Comment: Their API documentation asks me to use parenthesis. Doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: @90abyss that's very odd for a REST API and is sort of "going against the grain" ... why would they require parenthesis in a REST URL?

Have you tried removing the single quotes?

Comment: This is a REST API not a function call ... there should be no parenthesis or single quotes or anything else ... it should be /customers/date .... may want to give them a call ;)